# Index is being loaded from persisted on-disk snapshot after indexer process restart

Tags: couchbase

Index is being loaded from persisted on-disk snapshot after indexer process restart. It is NOT serving scan requests yet.
[image]
 "msg": " Index not ready for serving queries from [127.0.0.1:9101] - cause:  Index not ready for serving queries from [127.0.0.1:9101]",

Can anyone help me?

Comment: It looks like the indexer process is not able to warmup. You can check the indexer.log file for errors located under /opt/couchbase/var/lib/couchbase/logs. What is the CB server version being used, CE or EE?

Comment: thank your for your reply , now problem is solved , i restart the couchbase   and index are ready. but another problem is occurred new index are not created

show the error message
[
  {
    "code": 5000,
    "msg": "GSI CreatePrimaryIndex() - cause: Create index or Alter replica cannot proceed due to rebalance in progress, another concurrent create index request, network partition, node failover, indexer failure, or presence of duplicate index name.",
    "query": "CREATE PRIMARY INDEX `customer_requests_indx` ON `customer_requests`\n"
  }
]

Answer (score 0):

**error message [ { "code": 5000, "msg": "GSI CreatePrimaryIndex()**

this is because of indexer process went into hung state because of resource isseu. use pmap or mmap  and check how much your indexer process is using on server.